# ASP.NET MVC httpclient postasync timeout after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, httpclient

I'm trying to do an httpclient postasync and it works when I run it locally but not after I publish it.

```
public async Task<OrderRecord> GetOrderRecord(CheckOutRecord checkOutRecord)
        {          

            OrderRecord orderRecord = new OrderRecord();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100000);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://somewhere.com/Test/TestCheckout/", checkOutRecord);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {                        
                        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        orderRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRecord>(result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Info(response.RequestMessage);
                    }   
                }
                catch(HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex);
                    logger.Error("GetORderRecord failed.  CheckOutRecord: " + checkOutRecord);

                    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                }

            }

            return orderRecord;
        }
```

Here is the error message:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond "server ip address"
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MotorcraftCheckoutService.WebApplication.Controllers.OrderController.d__8.MoveNext()

Any idea's?  If I run it locally and point it to the remote location it works.  If I run it and point it to my machine it works.  Does not work after I publish to the webserver.

Comment: `Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond "server ip address" at...` Does _somewhere.com_ or the webserver have a firewall?

Comment: Yes it does but the application is calling itself.  /Order/GetData -> /Test/ReturnData.  This is a test that will eventually call our clients web service and retrieve data.